# Installing a package with a renamed dependent package

Tags: 20.04

I am trying to install libjson-xs-perl on Ubuntu 20.04.

One of the dependent packages is perlapi-5.28.1.

However, perlapi is only available on Ubuntu 20.04 as perl-base-5.30.0:
https://pkgs.org/download/perlapi-5.30.0

So even after installing perl-base, when I install libjson-xs-perl, the system still tells me that

```
Package perlapi-5.28.1 is not installed.
```

(I have checked with dpkg --list that perl-base is installed)

Any Linux guru can help? Thanks!

One critical constraint I have is that my machine does not have internet assess so I can only install packages with .deb transferred from other machines.

Comment: which is the name of the deb file that you are using for libjson-xs-perl installation? where did you get it? Maybe there's a chance that you are not using the correct deb for your ubuntu version.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion you are installing a version of libjson-xs-perl that doesn't fit for Ubuntu 20.04 focal.

If you check here: https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/libjson-xs-perl
you can see that libjson-xs-perl has been built with the proper dependencies in focal fossa (it is written that it uses perlapi-5.30.0 but not perlapi-5.28.1. ).

Download the deb file using the correct link from the "Download libjson-xs-perl" table in the same page.

Comment: Problem solved! As you suggested, the package I used did not fit for ubuntu 20.04 focal, although there was no "unfit" message pops up when I install it (instead I got the "Package perlapi-5.28.1 is not installed." message as aforementioned).

Comment: Could you explain in which way exactly? It may be useful also for other users :-)

Comment: Comment edited as you suggested. How would you normally distinguish if a package is suitable for Ubuntu 20.04 focal? (in my case libjson-xs-perl_4.020-1build1_amd64 is suitable while libjson-xs-perl_4.020-1_amd64 isn't.) Thank you @Lorenz Keel.

Comment: Good to hear. If you use Ubuntu, maybe it's better to get the .deb packages from https://packages.ubuntu.com/ (selecting the correct version of Ubuntu) instead of https://pkgs.org (that is more Debian focused). If my answer solved your problem, you should vote it :-)

Comment: I check always in https://packages.ubuntu.com/ which is the version of a package for my OS version.

Comment: Thanks! And yes I voted for your answer, unfortunately I need to have 15 reputations in order for my vote to show up =P